# Why $k$ must be subset of $Z(M_{n}(k))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, field-theory

My professor defined an algebra $R$ as follows:\

It is $(R = M_{n}(k), +, \times, .)$ such that:

1-$(R, +, \times)$ is a ring.

2- $k \subset R$ is a subring which is a field.

3- $. : k \times R \rightarrow R$ is the scalar multiplication such that:

$$c(r_{1} r_{2}) = (cr_{1}) r_{2} = r_{1} (cr_{2}) \forall c\in k, r_{1},r_{2} \in R.$$

Then when I asked him if this subset $k$ be the set of invertible matrices, he said no and he said this subset $k$ is $\{cI| c \in k \} \subset Z(M_{n}(k)).$

**My questions are:**

1- I do not know why he defined $k$ like that, could anyone explain this for me please?

2- I do not know why this definition of $k$ makes it $\subset Z(M_{n}(k)).$ Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: The set of invertible mateix does not form a field: sum of two invertible matrices might not be invertible.

Comment: Amd it is not clear what you are asking: it seems you are describing an example of an algebra, but you did not tell us what is R. I guess it is $M_n(k)$, please clarify

Comment: It looks like $(2)$ is true iff $k$ is commutative and $k$ is not necessarily in your case...unless I am reading this wrong.

Comment: @ArcticChar yes I agree for your first comment. fpr your second comment you are correct $R = M_{n}(k)$, sorry about that, I edited my post.

Comment: @DerekLuna My professor did not said that 2 is true iff $k$ is commutative, may be this is something I should conclude, I do not know.

Comment: The scalar multiples of the identity commute with every matrix. $(kI)M=kM=M(kI)$.

Comment: Yes, but I didn’t know that each $k$ was necessarily a scalar. In his case, they are all invertible matrices, right?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin and why he defined $k$ like that?

Comment: @DerekLuna what about the case $k=0$?

Comment: I was using $k$ in my comment as an individual constant. There is a copy of the field of definition inside the ring of matrices over that field, where the constant $a$ maps to the matrix $aI$. This is a central subring of the ring of matrices.  The ring of matrices over a field $k$ is a classical example of a noncommutative algebra over a field.